# Customer default rate - joint distribution, marginal distribution when sum not equal 1

Tags: joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

hope this question fits here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Background:

I´m working on a data generator for customer default data.
The default rate shall depend on multiple categorical independant characteristics.
The marginal distributions shall be adjustable.

### The issue:

The default rates for a specific characteristic don´t necessarly add up to 1.
This leads to changed marginal distributions in the data, when the multiple default rates for the different characteristics of a customer are multiplied to get his overall default rate.

### Example:

Let´s say I have two characteristics, whether an email is provided & whether a phone number is provided for that customer.
Furthermore, let´s say the marginal distributions for those characteristics shall be:

*email default rates*:
$
\begin{cases}
0.1&\text{if email provided}\\
0.6&\text{if no email provided}\\
\end{cases}
$

*phone default rates*:
$
\begin{cases}
0.3&\text{if phone nr. provided}\\
0.6&\text{if no phone nr. provided}\\
\end{cases}
$

This leads me to this table of joint & marginal distributions:

| email \ phone | provided | not provided | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| provided | 0.03 | 0.06 | 0.09 |
| not provided | 0.18 | 0.36 | 0.54 |
| sum | 0.21 | 0.42 | 0.63 |

Which, of course, doesn´t fit the originally supplied marginal distribution.
My question would be, has anybody an idea how to make this work so in the end, the supplied marginal distributions appear in the joint distribution table?

My idea was "normalizing" the original marginal distributions by a factor, depending on how both marginal dist. sums differ from one.
But I just can´t find a proper way to approach this. University is too long behind and I also couldn´t find any good answers either on here or via google search.

So maybe one of you has an idea for me how to get this working?
Thanks in advance for your time and effort!

Best regards,
z